# Not able to send email notification using Scala in Spark Yarn Cluster mode

Tags: scala, jakarta-mail

I have written a simple scala code for testing email Spark Yarn Cluster mode, initially i used to get class not found error then i created a maven fat jar and added mail-1.4.7.jar into the fat jar, after this i am getting the below error, the same code is working in yarn-client and local mode.

spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --jars /home/srv/mail-1.4.7.jar --class com.test.testmail /home/srv/spark/jar/test_mail.jar

```
import javax.mail.{ Message, Session }
import javax.mail.internet.{ InternetAddress, MimeBodyPart, MimeMessage, MimeMultipart }
import javax.activation.{ CommandMap, MailcapCommandMap }
import javax.mail.Transport

object testmail {
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    var fromMail = "ZZZZ@ZZZZ.com"
    var toMail = "ZZZZ@ZZZZ.com"
    var smtp_host = "ZZZZ.ZZZZ.com"
    var properties = System.getProperties()
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", smtp_host);
    var session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
    var message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromMail))
    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(toMail))
    message.setSubject("Ping");  
    message.setTeZt("Hello, this is example of sending email  ")
    Transport.send(message)
}
}
```

20/09/18 09:03:53 ERROR yarn.Client: Application diagnostics message: User class threw exception: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 550 5.7.1 Initial access check failure
; nested exception is: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSenderFailedException: 550 5.7.1 Initial access check failure

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your post and append a minimal reproducible example that is "running" = showing the error.

Comment: This error arises when the SMTP server you're connecting to decides the mail you're sending is against its policy.  Spark has nothing to do with this.  If it's working locally for you, it's most likely that the SMTP server is configured to not allow mails to be sent from the computers which make up your YARN cluster.  You'll need to work with the people who manage the SMTP server to either allow email to be sent from the cluster or find an SMTP server which will allow the cluster to send mail.

Comment: @SridharViswanathan see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024886/java-mail-initial-access-check-failure